# Dúvida com JSP - Message

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsp

Estou precisando de ajuda, para exibir uma mensagem através da fmt:message.

A situação é a seguinte. Eu tenho um formulário que é submetido via $.post. No controller que recebe essa requisição, eu faço uma validação através do BindingResult.

Caso tenha erro, eu retorno um JSON contendo os erros encontrados. Ao retornar ao formulário eu crio um alert com o Bootstrap para mostrar ao usuário o erro encontrado.

Com o seguinte trecho:

```
var str = "field.required.departamento.nome";
str = $("<div></div>").addClass("alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade in").
text('<fmt:message key="'+str+'"/>');
```

No navegador aparece apenas o resultado:

```
???field.required.departamento.nome???
```

Fiz alguns testes, e quando executo o mesmo código com essa propriedade setada no lugar da variável o código funciona normalmente.

Alguma dica, ajuda a respeito dessa dúvida?

Comment: Acho que esse `fmt` não funcionará. JSP é renderizado no servidor.